# How to undo "sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf"

Tags: macos, terminal, apache, php

After I did this:

```
sudo unlink /usr/local/php5
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/php5-*
```

To remove the supplemental configuration file that was installed with the updated PHP software, you may be able to remove the config file at /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf:

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

php stopped running even when I see the version of php -- using

```
php -v
PHP 5.5.6 (cli) (built: Nov 14 2013 14:08:56) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

Can anybody tell me why that is?

Comment: Any message when you run: sudo apachectl configtest  ??

Comment: [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax OK

Comment: Sounds to me like you are loading telling apache to load the old module first, which doesn't exist or is broken, then when it encounters the instructions to load the new module it doesn't even try because it tried already...

Answer (score 1):

You can't undo what you did, unless you can recover the files from a Time Machine backup. PHP probably stopped running because you removed files it needs.

Comment: After I added Include /private/etc/apache2/other/+php-osx.conf to httpd.conf php started running again on apache but showing older version. I guess, I need to add LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/php5/libphp5.so also.